# Why is NServiceBus Bus.Publish() not transactional?

Tags: nservicebus

**Setup**:
I have a couple of subscribers subscribing to an event produced by a publisher on the same machine via MSMQ. The subscribers use two different endpoint names, and are run in its respective process.  (This is NSB 4.6.3)

**Scenario**:
Now, if I do something "bad" to one of the subscribers (say remove proper permission in MSMQ to receive messages, or delete the queue in MSMQ outright...), and call Bus.Publish(), I will still have one event successfully published to the "good" subscriber (if the good one precedes the bad one on the subscriber list in subscription storage), or none successful (if the bad one precedes the good one).

**Conclusion**:
The upshot here is that Bus.Publish() does not seem to be transactional, as to making publishing to subscribers all succeed or all fail. Depending on the order of the subscribers on the list, the end result might be different.

**Questions**:
Is this behavior by design? 
What is the thought behind this?
If I want to make this call transactional, what is the recommended way?  (One option seems  to enclose Bus.Publish() in a TransactionScope in my code...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Publish is transactional, or at least, it is if there is an ambient transaction. Assuming you have not taken steps to disable transactions, all message handlers have an ambient transaction running when you enter the Handle method. (Inspect `Transaction.Current.TransactionInformation` to see first-hand.) If you are operating out of an `IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops`, however, there will be no ambient transaction, so then yes you would need to wrap with your own `TransactionScope`.

How delivery is handled (specific for the MSMQ transport) is different depending upon whether the destination is a local or remote queue.

**Remote Queues**

For a remote queue, delivery is not directly handled by the publisher at all. It simply drops the two messages in the "Outbox", so to speak. MSMQ uses store-and-forward to ensure that these messages are eventually delivered to their intended destinations, whether that be on the same machine or a remote machine. In these cases, you may look at your outgoing queues and see that there are messages stuck there that are unable to be delivered because of whatever you have done to their destinations.

The safety afforded by store-and-forward mean that one errant subscriber cannot take down a publisher, and so overall coupling is reduced. This is a good thing! But it also means that monitoring outgoing queues is a very important part of your DevOps story when deploying an NServiceBus system.

**Local Queues**

For local queues, MSMQ may still technically use a concept of an outoging queue in its own plumbing - I'm not sure and it doesn't really matter. But an additional step that MSMQ is capable of doing (and does) is to check the existence of a local queue before you try to send to it, and will throw an exception if it doesn't exist or something is wrong with it. This would indeed affect the publisher.

So yes, if you publish a message from a non-transactional state like the inside of an `IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops`, and the downed queue happens to be #2 on the list in subscription storage, you could observe a message arriving at SubscriberA but not at Subscriber B. If it were within a message handler with transactions disabled, you could see the multiple copies arriving at SubscriberA because of the message retry logic!

**Upshot**

`IWantToRunWhenBusStartsAndStops` is great for quick demos and proving things out, but try to put as little real logic in them as possible, opting instead for the safety of message handlers where the ambient transaction applies. Also remember than an exception inside there could potentially take down your host process. Certainly don't publish inside of one without wrapping it with your own transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, David. In my observation, MSMQ cut the corner when the message is addressed to a local queue, so does not place the message in outgoing queues. when it could not place the message onto the local destination queue directly, it raises an error, which propagates to NSB and causes publishing to succeed/fail partially. Is there some setting I missed in MSMQ to force it to always place a message in outgoing queues first?

Comment: Totally forgot MSMQ would do that. Updated my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the great writing, David!

Comment: Is the behavior any different than this if you use SQLTransport?